# Ruby | 2 float number multiple not giving the exact value

Tags: ruby

I have 2 float number and I try to get the multiple. But in the console it does not get the correct one. I do not know maybe there is a leak ?

```
{"price"=>"0.049391", "size"=>"0.001"}
```

When I multiple them console shows;

```
************
0.049391
************
0.001
************
4.9390999999999995e-05
************
```

Then when I push this data to array and in front end when I `console.log`

I get;

```
0.000049390999999999995
```

Why it is not  `0.0000493901` ?

Comment: The latter is a more precise representation of the same number. Why would you want the less precise scientific notation?

Comment: "Why it is not  0.0000493901" - ah, __now__ I can cast that close vote :)

Comment: But the calculation is not true, I do not need that precise number. I would like to get what google calculator gives :) which is 0.0000493901

Comment: Somebody, please dup-close this, I wasted my vote: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: No you did not my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

`4.9390999999999995e-05` and `0.000049390999999999995` are the same number. `e-05` is nothing more than notation for "move the decimal place five spots to the left".

Comment: The OP wants 0.000049391, not 0.000049390999999999995

Comment: Ah, right you are. Well in that case OP is SOL, because this is just a quirk of floating point precision, and the answer has been rightly marked as a duplicate.